# is there any possible way to achieve UIAutomation for TouchID in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, appium, ui-automation, touch-id

I would like to know if there is any possible way to automate Touch ID from the command line or is there any framework available to do the same.

I have developed an application which logins the user using password, later on displays the Touch ID prompt to register the user for Touch ID. I can manually test this functionality in simulator by turning on the hardware Touch ID capabilities but I am wondering same can be achieved through automation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Appium](http://appium.io/). It's an automated testing framework that lets you enroll the finger print and, whenever you need, it also gives you the possibility to simulato a touch of a matching/non-matching finger.